# Full screen Android google map v2 without grey grids on top and bottom

Tags: android, zooming, android-maps-v2

Using Android Google Maps v2 I want the map boundaries to match with phone screen width and height so that grey grids at the bottom and top of the map does not appear.

Moreover I had idea which can be used as workaround to restrict the zoom level of map to certain level. I can get the map zoom level with map.getCameraPosition().zoom
But map.setZoom(..) is not available in google map v2. But how to set the Zoom ? Can we restrict the map to certain zoomIn level ?

Another question is related to android map repeat after itself after scrolling .Can we restrict it ?If not can we know the bounds or co ordinates or anything whether the map is starting again .

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker?hl=fr-CA

Comment: @Harshid ..I have already gone through that document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to restrict the zoom level.  Here the minimum zoom level is set to 5.  If the user tries to zoom out any further than the camera is animated back to the minimum level.  Just replace MIN_ZOOM with the value you want to be the minimum zoom level.

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cp) {             
        final float MIN_ZOOM = 5.0f;                

        if (cp.zoom < MIN_ZOOM){                
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(cp.target)                      
                    .bearing(cp.bearing)
                    .tilt(cp.tilt)      
                    .zoom(MIN_ZOOM) 
                    .build();                       

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));                  
        }
    }
});
```